# how to add previous,play/stop,next in windows 10 minimizes

Tags: electron

how to add Previous,Play/Stop,Next into my electron app same as in Spotify

I don't know how to make or do that

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thumbnail Toolbars in Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/windows-taskbar#thumbnail-toolbars)

> To set thumbnail toolbar in your application, you need to use [BrowserWindow.setThumbarButtons](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetthumbarbuttonsbuttons-windows).

[win.setThumbarButtons(buttons)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetthumbarbuttonsbuttons-windows)

> Add a thumbnail toolbar with a specified set of buttons to the thumbnail image of a window in a taskbar button layout. Returns a Boolean object indicates whether the thumbnail has been added successfully.

The documentation follows, not a lot to explain there.